# How to refresh the list view from Service?

Tags: android, listview, android-service

In my application am using Service, Am start the Service from activity A, i have list view in activity A, how to refresh that list view in services?

**Activity A**

```
// in this class I have list view
Intent service = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Time_out_services.class);
startService(service);
```

**Services class**

```
public class Time_out_services extends Service{

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO do something useful

        mHandler.postDelayed(first_Task, 2*60 * 1000);

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    Runnable first_Task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // I want to refresh the list view here
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: use notifyDataSetChanged() when you finish with your updation.

Comment: Look up on how to use broadcastReceiver http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: i don't know how to update the list view.

Answer (score 0):

define a broadcastReceiver for update listveiw in your activity and too you should have a class for parcle content that you want add to listview from service for this you should define a class that implements Parcelable  and then putextra that to a intent and then send intent to reciever from service and then in   onrecieve method get that parcle with getextera and get  content from it and add content to listview.

see

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

for update listview you should in onrecieve method of broadcastReceiver add content to arraylist that you set in adapter of listview and then notify listview for changes